# Calculate sum of diagonals in a two-dimensional array

Tags: java

I'm studying/practicing and I found this code that prints a 3x3 grid 1-9. It adds up the 2 diagonals. I understand the first equation `if (i == j) {d1 += grid[i][j]; // math for d1}` but I don't understand the second one `if ((i + j) == (grid_size - 1)) {d2 += grid[i][j]; // math for d2}`.

What is the `i + j` do in the second equation? I know the `grid_size - 1` starts from the end and works in, but confused on the `i + j`. Unlike the first equation `i == j`, what is `i + j` checking in the second one?
`

```
public static void getGrid() {
    System.out.println("Below we will see a 3x3 grid with the numbers 1-9:");
    System.out.println(); // space for eye candy

    int grid[][] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

    // display matrix using for loops
    // outer loop for row
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        // inner loop for column
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println(); 
    }

    // diagonal work
    int grid_size = 3;
    int d1 = 0; // setting diagonal
    int d2 = 0; // setting diagnoal

    for (int i = 0; i < grid_size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid_size; j++) {

            if (i == j) {
                d1 += grid[i][j]; // math for d1
            }

            if ((i + j) == (grid_size - 1)) {
                d2 += grid[i][j]; // math for d2
            }

        }
    }
```

I searched online but I couldn't find the code again.
I'm expecting the answer to what does `i + j` check for in the second equation.

Comment: `i` is the outer loop counter, `j` is in the inner loop counter. It's testing if `i + j` is equal to the size of the grid. Why? Because that's when it's on a diagonal. The other arm of the diagonal.

Comment: draw a 5 by 5 grid. Write the coordinates of the diagonal from the upper right to the lower left.  Do you notice a pattern?

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps you to understand,

[image]

Comment: Woooow. Thanks man haha. After seeing how you have it I 100% understand. Definitely had  one of those "well duh" moments, thank you!